# How to get hyperlink in wordpress php?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am building a website and i have this issue :

I am working on a template and i did some modification.  So the front page have some boxes which shows deals and buttons. 
[image]

As you can see there are buttons called "See Deals"

Each box is a post so when i create a post then each box created automatically . I want that when i put a link on post then it will automatically set behind that "See Deals" button. I mean i want that this "See deal" button take the url from a link which i put in this post.

I wrote this code for boxes :

```
<div class="price_row_grid">
    <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
        <?php theme_create_btn('no', 'price'); ?>

    </div>

    <div class="floatright vendor_for_grid">
        <?php if ($price_meta == 'admin'): ?>
            <?php $author_id = $post->post_author; ?>
            <a class="admin" href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url($author_id) ?>" title="<?php the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id); ?>">
                <?php echo get_avatar($author_id, '22'); ?>
            </a>
        <?php elseif ($price_meta == 'store'): ?>
            <div class="brand_logo_small">
                <?php WPSM_Postfilters::re_show_brand_tax('logo'); //show brand logo?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>


 <div class="price_row_grid">
        <div class="price_for_grid floatleft">
            <p class="button"><a href ="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">Get Deal</a></p>



        </div>
```

Now suppose i created a post on wordpress :

[image]

Now you can see there i put a dummy link at the end of post "google" now i want that when i put any link there then the box of this post get this link and set behind "Get Deal" button.

Comment: you can create your own links shot-codes or use pods.io